# Running external program through python terminal

Tags: python, operating-system, system, external, execute

i try to run a program( a stemmer with a tcl file) to read a txt file and save the result into an other txt file. When i run the command through dos-windows terminal it works fine, but when i run this through python terminal with `os.system()` it returns `1` value and nothing happens..
Here is the code:

```
>>>import os
>>>os.system('C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\tclsh.exe -encoding utf-8     C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\GreekStemmer.tcl in.txt out.txt')
>>>1
```

I guess '1' means that the command didnt executed succesfully?? And when i run this in dos-terminal it creates the out.txt file with the result.But here not..

Comment: You need to add an 'r' prefix on strings with unescaped backslashes in them like in the argument you're trying to pass to `os.system()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On my machine the following doesn't work, because the backslashes are not interpretted. They indicate special charachters.

```
import os
os.system('C:\bin\Tcl\bin\tclsh.exe')
```

You can add an r before the string

```
import os
os.system(r'C:\bin\Tcl\bin\tclsh.exe')
```

or use doubled backslases

```
import os
os.system('C:\\bin\\Tcl\\bin\\tclsh.exe')
```

Answer (score 0):

Is `in.txt` in the same directory that you are running your python script from?  You may be misinterpreting where the current working directory is from your function call.  If not, instead of `in.txt` give a more specific path.

Also, there is a `subprocess` module for external executable calls in python.

Comment: in.txt is in the same directory and i also tried to give full path for the in.txt. Subprocess returns error

Comment: Just confirming, the same directory that you are in before calling the python script, or the same directory as your .tcl file?  Because it needs to be the former

Comment: All files and executables are in the same directory.. :(