# How to launch an external program in a python script

Tags: python-2.7

I am creating a Python script where it does a bunch of tasks and one of those tasks is to launch and open google chrome. What is the ideal way of accomplishing that in my script?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/webbrowser.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [Running external program through python terminal](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13582904/running-external-program-through-python-terminal)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can launch anything from python as a command line call.  This is done with [Subprocess](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html).

For example:

```
import subprocess

sp = subprocess.Popen("PATH_TO_CHROME\chrome")
#If you want your process to wait for chrome to "complete"
ret_val = sp.wait()
#or
sp_out, sp_error = sp.communicate()
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try with:

[Subprocess.call](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#using-the-subprocess-module)

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(['C:\\Users\username\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe with commands.

```
import commands

a = commands.getoutput("./PATH_TO_CHROME/chrome")
```